# Displaying data from database using keyboard in jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, user-input

I am working on a JDBC project for the first time. I have a table in a MySQL database as shown in image:

[image: click here to view database table as i do not have permission to post image directly]

This is my code which displays complete table

```
//load Driver class
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

//get Connection
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/School", "root", "1947");

 //get statement
Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 

 //load ResultSet
ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("select  *from Student");
```

I want to display data according to rollno i.e System first ask for a rollno. When the user inputs the rollno, it should display all the details related to this rollno. Is it possible?

Comment: That said, you could have posted DDL instead, or otherwise that table output as code formatted text.

Comment: Your question is actually two entirely separate concerns. You are making your question (and likely your code) more complicated by combining asking for user input and executing queries in a single question. If you separate these concerns, you can ask those as separate questions (or, more likely, you'll find suitable questions that already answer those parts separately). As an added bonus, your code will likely become better as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your comment flag has been declined. Please read about [how to flag comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801/when-is-a-comment-hostile-or-unfriendly-educating-newer-users-how-to-flag-comm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Scanner to ask for rollno and PreparedStatement to set parameters in your query

```
    java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    int rollNo = sc.nextInt();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Student where rollno=?");
        ps.setInt(1, rollNo);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Integer rollno = rs.getInt("rollno");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            //other columns
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please learn about try-with-resources (introduced in Java 7), it would reduce this code by about 66%.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to scan for the input which is toll number then include it in your query to filter results by roll number using where clause